# ¿Como insertar datos al siguiente modelo de mongo mediante Postman?

Tags: json, array, nodejs, mongodb, postman

Este es mi modelo de base de datos el cual cuenta con arrays dentro de un array, estoy un poco confundido también en esa parte, acepto criticas y sugerencias comunidad

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');

autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose);

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let centralSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    alias: {
        type: String,
    },
    siglas: {
        type: String,
    },
    tipoCentral: [{
        tipo: {
            type: String
        }
    }],
    ubicacion: {
        type: String,
    },
    direccion: {
        type: String
    },
    location: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: "Point"
        },
        coordinates: [{
            type: Number
        }]
    },
    criticity: {
        type: Number,
    },
    //campo para definir status en la bd
    estado: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }

});

//crea el id autoincrementable 
centralSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
    model: '_id',
    field: '_id',
    startAt: 1,
    incrementBy: 1
});

centralSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {
    message: '{PATH} Debe ser único y diferente'
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Central', centralSchema);
```

En Postman hago la inserción de la siguiente manera mostrada en formato json pero no puedo por el error que aparece supongo que es por los id o no se si la estructura esta de manera correcta,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logre introducir datos con una consulta en Mongo pero quiero hacerlo desde Postman ya que aquí esta la conexión directa de la app en linea y yo lo hice en consulta pero en la base de datos local
anexo query que utilice en consola de mongo

```
db.centrals.insert( {"id": 738,   "location": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-102.969648, 21.951073] },"estado": true,"name": "CLV0032 Alcatel7330", "alias": "CLV0032 Alcatel7330","siglas": "CLV32","tipoCentral": [{ "_id": {"_id": 200},"tipo": "URE"}],     "criticity": 20,"_v": 0 })
```

Comment: MongoDB crea automaticamente los campos `_id`. Si le mandas un valor debe ser generado con ObjectId. Si no lo haces asi, debes desactivar el campo _id de algun modo. Pero, verdaderamente necesitas estas solución?. El numero auto incremental generalmente se omite en mongodb, suele estar mas relacionado al sql.

Comment: Si entiendo que los campos los crea automáticamente, de igual manera intente sin los campos id pero aparece el mismo error y si yo se que no es algo correcto pero es un Backend ya creado que no puedo modificar por ello tengo que hacer las pruebas forzosamente asi